# Using list() or similar to achieve left-hand assignment while conserving array for all other parameters than the first

Tags: php, arrays, split

The title doesn't give it away, i know. If there is a solution to this, it probably involves some decent trickery.

**Situation**

I'll explain via code:

```
$str = 'all.your.base';
list($a, $b, $c) = explode('.', $str);
```

`$a`, `$b` and `$c` will be set accordingly.

However, what i want to achieve is more like this:

```
$str = 'all.your.base';
list($a, $rest) = explode('.', $str);
```

Whereas afterwards `$a` should contain `'all'` and `$rest` should be an array that looks like this: `['your', 'base']`

Clearly, this can be done easily by other means, but as i wrote a few lines of code to get there, i was wondering if there is not a solution at hand such as `list()` that maybe i am unaware of, which can – with some trickery – provide the desired result in a shorter, quicker and neater fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the third argument to `explode`, [**`limit`**](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php#refsect1-function.explode-parameters)

```
$str = 'all.your.base';
list($a, $rest) = explode('.', $str, 2);
```

Comment: Very nice! I had no idea `explode()` was willing to take a third parameter! Awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Do you see a quick and easy way to invert this, so that a variable gets the value of the last component of the splitted string, and another becomes an array containing all previous components (but in the original order) ?

Comment: @SquareCat ah, I see. Sorry, I didn't read your question correctly

Comment: Nono, the original one was answered correctly. Here's the follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616906/using-list-or-similar-to-achieve-left-hand-assignment-resulting-in-an-array-fo

Comment: @SquareCat well, I could have sworn your initial query was for `$rest` to be a string with `"your.base"` but that's not what your question is asking

Comment: The goal here was to have an array `$rest` containing `["your", "base"]`. While implementing your solution i realized it was not what i was looking for. I confused the order of data in the string. Sorry for the confusion.