# Using list() or similar to achieve left-hand assignment resulting in an array for all other parameters than the last

Tags: php, arrays, split

This is a follow-up question to:

[Using list() or similar to achieve left-hand assignment while conserving array for all other parameters than the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616759/using-list-or-similar-to-achieve-left-hand-assignment-while-conserving-array-f/42616783#42616783)

**Situation**

```
$str = 'all.your.base';
list($a, $b, $c) = explode('.', $str);
```

`$a`, `$b` and `$c` will be set accordingly.

However, what i want to achieve is this:

```
$str = 'all.your.base';
list($prev, $final) = explode('.', $str);
```

Whereas afterwards `$final` should contain `'base'` and `$prev` should be an array that looks like this: `['all', 'your']`

While this can be done easily by other means, i look for a solution such as `list()` that maybe i am unaware of, which can achieve this as a single-liner or with the least code possible. Potentially involving interleaved `explode()` and `implode` calls and some string reversal?

Comment: I don't understand why you're posting the same exact question with no modifications whatsoever when you've already accepted an answer to to the duplicate question you just asked not 30 minutes ago.

Comment: It is not the same question. It covers a different problem and requires a different solution. Read before vote, please.

Comment: I mean, technically it is the same question. You just reversed the parameters of the problem. `explode` accepts negative integers for the third argument. `$prev = explode('.', $str, -1); list(,,$final) = explode('.', $str);`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work this way, as Phil stated, but the hint with the negative integers is a good one (only supported from PHP 5.1 onwards)

Comment: Ummm... sure it does. The values of `$prev` and `$final` are exactly what you stated you expect. `$final = 'base'` and `$prev = ['all', 'your']` Not sure what you're talking about that doesn't work.

Comment: WAT? You expect to support < 5.1?!?! I don't even...

Comment: But doesn't the approach rely on the pre-runtime knowledge of how many components the string will have?

Comment: No. From the manual: [If the limit parameter is negative, all components except the last -limit are returned](http://php.net/explode) if your requirements are to get all but the last element from the delimiter then there are no unknowns.

Comment: Yes, but what about `list(,,$final)` – it looks to me like i would have to `eval()` the whole thing in order to be able to make this call. Or am i missing a vital point here? There is no knowledge of how many commas will be needed aforehand, as the string is not present at the time of coding.

Comment: You seem too caught up in finding a way to use list comprehension when you don't need it. You're trying to mutate the array, not consume it. In other words: `$prev = explode('.', $str); $final = array_pop($prev);` gives you exactly what you want. Don't try to find a problem that fits the solution when you've already got a solution that solves the problem.

Comment: Good point. I was looking for a one-liner though, but i guess that's not possible. For the sake of it being potentially possible, i'll wait and see if someone can come up with one. But your approach is already pretty neat. Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly my point. Rather than look for a solution to the problem you're awaiting a problem that is solved by your preconceived solution. Good luck with that.

Comment: Not exactly, no. This is about finding the simple-most solution possible to this problem. I have solved the problem before posting my very original question, but with three lines of code. You gave me two. I look for one. Nothing was wrong with using three lines. Nothing would be wrong applying your solution. But the question as such remains unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is a one liner (indented for readability's sake) that will return that. If you ever use that in production, don't tell them I did that. Here's a [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/NgnLu)

```
list($prev, $final) = [
    0 => array_slice(explode('.', $str), 0, -1),
    1 => array_pop(explode('.', $str))
];
var_dump($prev);
var_dump($final);
```

---

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "all" [1]=> string(4) "your" }
string(4) "base"
```

Comment: Aah, that's pretty likeable! Of course a catastrophe in itself, but that's precisely what i was looking for. Many thanks for your input!